# Is Dohop reliable?

Tags: europe, cancellations, delays

I used airline's website to book. From X to Y via Z.

I was charged 3 times. 2 for 2 flights, 1 for dohop

Connection is guaranteed by Dohop but title of the email Dohop sent me is "Booking confirmation X to Y with Transavia Smart Connect"

> Delays or cancellation of your flight
>
> If your flight is delayed or cancelled, Dohop will rebook you on an alternative flight to your final destination. To benefit from this service, please contact Dohop Connect as soon as possible by calling or sending a SMS to ... or by sending an e-mail to ....

Should I be worried? There are frequent strikes in Y

Comment: While this likely can be answered, it is much easier if you edit in the actual airports and airlines.

Comment: What is your citizenship/PR/visa situation for Y? A self-connection means you need to be able to enter Y (not just airside transit). Also do you have checked luggage? Do you have to go through entry or exit passport control? Transavia sell self-connections which are nearly impossible (and IMHO this is really completely illegal for the airline to sell like this).

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? "Transavia sell self-connections which are nearly impossible" - I can enter Y with the visa I have. No checked luggage. Y is the first entry into Schengen, so yes I will go through the passport control there. I will have about 2.5 hours of layover which is normally more than enough

Comment: You would probably get a much more specific answer if you could specify X, Y and Z, the flights/schedules involved, your citizenship/PR/visa status for the relevant countries (especially Y), the date of travel, and whether you have checked luggage, as it may all make the difference between “no chance ever” and “very small risk”.

Comment: I see connections with 2h05 transit time, when the check-in deadline is 1h before departure and there’s entry passport control. That’s extremely tight. 2h30 with no checked luggage, especially if you can do online check-in is slightly more reasonable, but does not leave much margin for error. Things may be very different if you travel on a quiet day or a very busy day (holidays etc.).

Comment: Just so I understand you correctly. You mean flights with 2hr transit time should be illegal? Why wouldn't it be possible to check-in online??

Comment: @oooooo No, I mean it’s probably illegal for Transavia to sell “connecting” flights without taking responsibility themselves for the whole trip, I wonder how they think they can get ignore EC261. But yes, additionally, selling self-connections with a 2h05 transit time when the check-in deadline is 1h before departure and people have to go through entry passport checks borders on deception.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible to check-in online?

Comment: @jcaron I'd put my grain of salt that it isn't illegal in the slightest if the customer is correctly informed, Ryanair has done that for 20+ years and hasn't had a single issue that I know of. If that was done covertly, yes, it would be, but in this state bad business practice, yes, illegal no

Comment: @oooooo there are many cases when online check-in is not possible, based on various combinations of the airline, the airport, the destination country, the citizenship of the passenger, etc. I don’t know the specifics in the case of Transavia (much less in your specific situation as we have very few details).

Comment: @NicolasFormichella do Ryanair sell connecting flights? When I try to book on their (mobile) website, once I have entered a departure airport, I am under the impression that they only show destinations with direct flights from the airport.

Comment: @jcaron I am struggling to analyse this and find exactly what could be illegal about it. I also think it feels a bit funny that Transavia would get involved directly and describe it in that way (as opposed to letting you do it on your own or through a third-party like Ryanair or Kayak do) but EU passenger rights regulations say absolutely nothing about that.

Comment: What could be actionable is refusing to offer the relevant guarantees and compensations if they were deemed to apply regardless. That's essentially a separate question and what they write in their FAQ doesn't really change their position in that respect. Maybe they just count on scary language and BS excuses to discourage claims, as legacy airlines are prone to do as well.

Comment: At best, it’s on the edge, clearly trying to circumvent EC261 case law on connecting flights, by selling those connecting flights, but then pretending they are not related by putting them on separate bookings/tickets. It’s one thing for a third-party OTA to do this, it’s really another for an airline to let you build an itinerary like that and marginally mention Dohop in the process. But I notice Transavia are not the only ones, Easyjet and quite a few others now do the same thing (using the services of Dohop as well). I guess we won’t know until this gets to court…

Comment: So if I miss my second flight and if Dohop "can't" find a replacement flight, I should file a dispute for 3 transactions (2 flights + dohop)? What does the EC261 case law say exactly regarding this case? Cause I can just copy paste that into the dispute form of my credit card in addition to a proof of them "failing" to find a replacement flight

Comment: @jcaron Yeah, that definitely feels shady, seems to be Dohop entire model. Thinking about it, the regulation also says you have to inform passengers of their rights and they do assume some responsibility (refund of the second flight plus a random low amount for a hotel room), just not at the level foreseen by the regulation (which seems an even weaker position than just pretending they have no responsibility whatsoever).

Answer (score 5):

> Should I be worried?

Yes. Self connections are generally a bad idea and the so-called "guarantee" has often very little value.

No one can really guarantee a connection so it all comes down to "what happens if you miss it".

This case seems to  be particularly problematic since Dohop appears to say "Transavia handles it" whereas Transavia says "Dohop handles it". At least Transavia is a bit more specific about it "https://www.transavia.com/help/en-eu/search-and-book/smart-connect/flight-delayed-or-cancelled".

> If it is not possible to find an alternative, Dohop will refund the unused part of your booking. If the new flight does not leave until the next day, Dohop will also refund the price of a hotel room (worth €60) and all meals (worth €15 per meal).

That's really bad. Dohop can simply say: "sorry, we could not find an alternative" and the only thing you get back is the money for the flight you missed. But you are still stuck in Y and have to figure out how to get to Z. Same-day or next-day flight tickets will often way more expensive than your original ticket.

Also: good luck finding a hotel room for 60 Euro close to a popular airport.

Comment: There are 4 flights to the same destination of the same airline in the same and next day. It is very unlikely that they will all be full. Can Dohop still say "sorry, we could not find an alternative"?

Comment: Flight can be 100% full and often are within Europe, even if there are 4 on the same day.

Comment: Can Dohop still say "sorry, we could not find an alternative" while in fact there are empty seats in many flights in the same day?

Comment: @oooooo if this were an EC261-protected connection (which I believe it should be, but they try to get out of it), they wouldn’t be allowed to do so. Here they can basically do anything they want, their T&Cs are full of “at Dohop’s sole discretion”… they probably don’t have any reason to do so, but you never know…

Comment: What is a EC261-protected connection?

Comment: @jcaron : I doubt you can claim EC261 here. EC 261 puts the responsibility on the "operating carrier". In this case the OP has two contracts with two different carriers and both fulfil there obligations. EC261 doesn't cover the case of a third party booking agent and it definitely does not cover the case of a third party booking agent selling you a self connection.

Comment: @oooooo I'm quite sure that Dohop's terms conditions state that they can choose what an acceptable alternative is. In practice that means if its cheaper for them to just refund you the money, that's what they will do. Unfortunately these are the terms and conditions that you agreed when booking this itinerary .

Comment: How can you be quite sure that Dohop's terms conditions state that they can choose what an acceptable alternative is? @Hilmar

Comment: I have read enough T&C and the associated  weasel language and also reports about KIWI to assume that, but, yes, I'm not 100% sure. Feel free to plow through it yourself and draw your own conclusions https://support.dohop.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021507179-Terms-Conditions

Comment: @Hilmar in this case it’s a single airline operating both flights, and selling both at the same time, but pretending they’re separate bookings and adding the Dohop service (and fee) to make it look like it’s guaranteed while providing guaranteed which are much lower than EC261 would require…

Comment: @jcaron: that would be a lot easier to assess if we actually knew who the airline was. But chances are the airline is using this construct to shed all liability for the connection. Example of easyJet's T&C "If you have booked an onward flight with easyJet or another carrier, this represents a separate contract of carriage. We do not guarantee or accept liability for missed onward carriage on a subsequent flight"

Comment: @Hilmar the airline here is Transavia, but they use the same service as EasyJet, provided by Dohop (“Transavia SmartConnect”, which is the same as “Easyjet Worldwide”). But it’s all branded with the carrier’s name, and other than a fleeting “you retrieve your bags and check-in again” it’s really difficult to guess that one is booking flights separately.

Comment: @jcaron which leads us to what exactly? Is there a way to proceed?  e.g contact some EC261 related EU entity?

Comment: @oooooo First, if despite the split bookings they still agree to EC261 claims as if it were a single itinerary, there is of course no issue (but then one would wonder why they do all this) — while implicitly that seems to be their goal, they never state so explicitly. Then, the issue can probably be brought before a court only if one has an EC261 claim due to a problem with the connection to which they respond negatively. But my guess is that they will try to settle before this gets judged to avoid building precedent.

Comment: @jcaron: that's fair. This is a fairly new construct and we won't get a legal interpretation of EC261 in this context until someone takes it to court.  Personally I  think that the airline will aggressively defend it (why else would they pay Dohop?) and at least easyJet specifically calls this case out in their T&C. But who knows?

Comment: @oooooo: There isn't much can you do at this point. If all goes as planned you will be fine. Problems will only occur if you miss your flight. For this case: make sure that you know the process and will be able to contact Dohop (SIM card, etc) and it's probably not a bad idea to research alternatives: what other flights can you take later that day or the next day.